# I cant get some urls contents

Tags: php

*I have a very strange problem hope someone can help me*

**This one working**

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
    echo $url;      
?>
```

**This one too**

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('http://www.typingclub.com');
    echo $url;      
?>
```

**But why this isnt working and how can i fix it?**

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('http://www.gittigidiyor.com');
    echo $url;      
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to `http://www.gittigidiyor.com`? I can't open it.

Comment: yes im accesing http://www.gittigidiyor.com and i live in turkey maybe this website block himself for other countries

Comment: @Mohammad      ........

Comment: Your code should work. But i think php server does not have access to target domain.

Comment: @Mohammad exactly, i was searching to fix this issue but so far i cant find anyting. u have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The url responds to requests - try curl - e.g.

```
curl http://www.gittigidiyor.com
```

To see the headers use

```
curl -i http://www.gittigidiyor.com
```

I believe it is because the header information from http://www.gittigidiyor.com indicates that the transfer encoding is chunked and this does not work in php prior to version 5.3.

You can use curl within your php as an alternate method to pull in file contents - see http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php